# Git replace inbetween commits with another branch commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Wanted to move things:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   (master)
      \
       \
        L--M--N--O--P    (feature)
```

Wanted to remove D-E-F commits and replace with L-M-N-O-P. The final repo should be

```
A--B--C--L--M--N--O--P--G--H  (master)
```

Unfortunately, my Git isn't strong enough yet, any help?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it: `git rebase F master --onto feature`

This tells Git to move the commits between `F..master` onto `feature`. Now your repo looks like

```
A--B--C--D--E--F
       \
        \
         L--M--N--O--P          (feature)
                      \
                       \
                        G--H    (master)
```

Then just `git branch -d feature` to clean up the old `feature` branch, and Git's garbage collection will take care of `D--E--F`.

For all sorts more detail and some good example diagrams, read through the [rebase docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Answer (score 0):

Your history looks like this:

```
$ git log --oneline  --graph --all
* 3e680f3 H
* afd87a5 G
* 2583117 F
* 6f44661 E
* 37ba1cd D
| * 7c8d70f P
| * b953a6f O
| * 7e2f28e N
| * 95fc381 M
| * 7ca7fe9 L
|/
* c30b405 C
* 70fad86 B
* 18aedd7 A
* c32e786 Initial commit
```

Merge the `feature` branch

```
$ git me feature
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 l | 0
 m | 0
 n | 0
 o | 0
 p | 0
 5 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 l
 create mode 100644 m
 create mode 100644 n
 create mode 100644 o
 create mode 100644 p
```

[Interactively](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Reordering-Commits) rebase your master, for me `c32e786` is the hash of the initial commit:

```
$ git rebase -i  c32e786
```

You will see a text editor with a list of commits in it. Remove unwanted commits and reorder the rest or them however you want:

```
$ git log --oneline
ff6a364 H
4a9d73c G
7c8d70f P
b953a6f O
7e2f28e N
95fc381 M
7ca7fe9 L
c30b405 C
70fad86 B
18aedd7 A
c32e786 Initial commit
```